# Disable test webjob

Tags: c#, azure, webjob

I'm testing webjob on the local machine, I create multiple sample type trigger wejob. Like in a project there are multiple queue trigger webjob, however, all of them point to the same queue, so I want to disable others to do a test.

[image]

Like the image above, there are two webjob functions, when I test I want only one working.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , especially  'Help others reproduce the problem' part, and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to implement it, firstly set the `Disable` attribute to your functions and add a `Disable` to your `appsettings.json` file.

[image]

[image]

The second way is use `"AzureWebJobs.YourFunctionName.Disabled": "true"` setting  to disable your function, set this setting in the `appsettings.json`.

[image]

Below is my test result, both functions are disabled.

[image]